# How to re-write non-WWW to WWW whilst also enforcing HTTPS in Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, virtualhost

I have a client who I am tidying things up for after a migration to a newer/faster server. One of the inclusions is to bring in SSL support, and also standardize links/URLs.

The goal is to force HTTPS (which they never had before now) and also re-write all URL's to include the www. prefix. My results are not as expected, but then I've never had to do this before, and the documentation doesnt specifically describe how to do this. This is what I've got:

```
server {
listen      80;
server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
rewrite     ^   https://www.domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  domain.com;
    #rewrite     ^   https://www.domain.com$request_uri? permanent;

    ssl                         on;
    ssl_certificate             /etc/nginx/ssl.d/domain.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key         /etc/nginx/ssl.d/domain.com.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 30m;
.....rest of vhost config in here.....
}
```

The above results in the following when typed into the URL bar:

```
http://domain.com -> https://www.domain.com
http://www.domain.com -> https://www.domain.com
**https://domain.com -> https://domain.com**
https://www.domain.com -> https://www.domain.com
```

The problem is the SSL, non-WWW url. This does not enforce WWW prefix, and I need it to. I tried to to do this with the commented out line that you see above. But this resulted in a redirect loop (to be expected really, but I dont know how else to do it).

Any ideas? This is the only domain on the server, and it's not currently live, so I can try anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it, if I understand your question correctly.

```
# Redirect all variations to https://www domain
server {
  listen 80;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.access.log main buffer=128k flush=60 if=$log_ua;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name example.com;

  ssl_certificate /var/lib/acme/certs/xx/fullchain;
  ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/acme/certs/xx/privkey;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.access.log main buffer=128k flush=60 if=$log_ua;

  # Set up preferred protocols and ciphers. TLS1.2 is required for HTTP/2
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

  # This is a cache for SSL connections
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:2m;
  ssl_session_timeout 60m;


  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for that. I tried that way and I run into redirect loop/errors. If it matters, the site is running Drupal, but it doesnt ahve any modules or anything that would mess with URL rewriting.

Comment: I would look really hard at Drupal. Try it with a single static HTML file instead of Drupal.

Comment: Good call, I'm not TOO clued up on drupal, and its a test migrated copy of the customers live site, so they could well have somehting in place messing with url redirects that I dont know about. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is `$base_url`  in `settings.php` defined?

Comment: @Tim your answer has a mistake in it. You are redirecting `http` to `https://www` but then not including the `www` in the `server_name` for `https` unless you mean to have another server block for the `www`

Comment: @Drifter104 these are just my redirect blocks. I have another main block that services the actual requests on https://www . The blocks I posted simply serve to redirect to that one main block.